# Time changes when converting date into ISOString in nodejs

Tags: node.js, datetime, timezone

I've got a date string from my database which has this format:

```
Tue Nov 12 2013 18:14:46 GMT+0100 (CET)
```

I want to convert it into a `ISOString` and im currently doing that with:

```
var iso = new Date(val.text_date).toISOString();
```

However for some reason the output time is moved 1 hour backwards? 
This is the output im getting:

```
2013-11-12T17:14:46.000Z
```

How can i avoid this?

Answer (score 2):

*Short answer:* the time is converted into UTC, and your original time was displayed in UTC+1, hence the one hour difference.

---

The `Date.toISOString()` method converts the date into a string in the ISO 8601 format. Note that the returned date in your example ends by a `Z`: `2013-11-12T17:14:46.000Z`. As per [the Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) and [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601):

> If the time is in UTC, add a Z directly after the time without a
>   space. Z is the zone designator for the zero UTC offset

Comment: This **is** the right zone to store datetime objects. In this way, you can't have weird issues when one variable is in UTC+1 and another is in UTC-6. To display it, use the [`.toString()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toString) or  [`toLocaleTimeString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString).